# Преобразование типов указателей

Tags: c++, указатели

Решил изучить преобразования указателей. И у меня возник вопрос по поводу этого кода:

```
unsigned short int a = 0xABCD;
unsigned int* ref_a = (unsigned int*) &a;
```

если я, допустим, буду и дальше работать с указателем ref_a, то я буду оперировать и с невыделенной памятью, которая нужна для представления int? Или эти два байта компилятор как-то выделит?

Comment: Это будет типичное неопределенное поведение... Реально будут использоваться 2 байта, которые лежат рядом с `a`, а что они реально собой представляют и что вы затрете при присваивании, например — кто знает?...

Comment: Обсуждение поведения программы с неопределённым поведением - пустая трата времени, если вы не читали получивший машинный код. Добавьте в вопрос машинный код, который произвёл ваш компилятор - появится предмет для обсуждения.

Comment: *`"я буду оперировать и с невыделенной памятью, которая нужна для представления int?"`* -- совершенно верно. Более того, на BE-архитектуре данные переменной `a` попадут в старшие (а не младшие, как видимо задамано) биты `*ref_a`

Answer (score 6):

При разыменовании указателя `ref_a` будет неопределенное поведение, так как тип объекта, на который тот реально указывает, не совместим с `unsigned int *`.

Answer (score 3):

Мне просто негде это расписать, так что простите, что ответом. Это ответ для `Bloody.cpp`, а заодно и всем, кому будет интересно.

Никакое т.н. *исключение* при такой работе Visual C++ не генерирует, это, как говорят в народе, путать теплое и мягкое. Это при отладочном режиме в среде используется дополнительный код, который заставляет отладчик выбросить окошко с сообщением о проблеме. Данный код включается ключом `/RTCs` (run-time check, stack) и добавляет в вызов функции дополнительную проверку, не изменяются ли дополнительные включенные в стек данные (т.н. "канарейка"). Естественно, никто в здравом уме не будет включать такой код, как и код, проверяющий выход за границы массива, например, в релиз-версию.

Вот пример кода

```
void f()
{
    unsigned short int a = 0xABCD;
    unsigned int* ref_a = (unsigned int*) &a;
    *ref_a = 0x12345678;
    cout << hex << a << endl;
    cout << hex << *ref_a << endl;
}
```

а вот цена включения проверок...

Без проверки:

```
?f@@YAXXZ PROC                      ; f
; File G:\Tmp\Test\test.cpp
; Line 6
$LN3:
    sub rsp, 104                ; 00000068H
; Line 7
    mov eax, 43981              ; 0000abcdH
    mov WORD PTR a$[rsp], ax
; Line 8
    lea rax, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
    mov QWORD PTR ref_a$[rsp], rax
; Line 9
    mov rax, QWORD PTR ref_a$[rsp]
    mov DWORD PTR [rax], 305419896      ; 12345678H
; Line 10

.... Вывод значений

; Line 12
    add rsp, 104                ; 00000068H
    ret 0
?f@@YAXXZ ENDP                      ; f
```

А вот тот же код, но с ключом `/RTCs`:

```
?f@@YAXXZ PROC                      ; f
; File G:\Tmp\Test\test.cpp
; Line 6
$LN3:
    push    rdi
    sub rsp, 112                ; 00000070H
    lea rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    mov ecx, 20
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
; Line 7
    mov eax, 43981              ; 0000abcdH
    mov WORD PTR a$[rsp], ax

    .... Далее все так же, как и выше

; Line 12
    mov rcx, rsp
    lea rdx, OFFSET FLAT:?f@@YAXXZ$rtcFrameData
    call    _RTC_CheckStackVars
    add rsp, 112                ; 00000070H
    pop rdi
    ret 0
?f@@YAXXZ ENDP                      ; f
```

Обратите внимание на заполнение стека в начале кода, и вызов функции проверки неизменности этих данных в конце.

Поэтому говорить о генерации исключения в этом коде неверно как с точки зрения терминологической, так и идеологической. По сути, это простая запись/чтение за границами массива, причем в стеке, что никак не вызовет срабатывания защиты памяти.

Неопределенность поведения заключается в том, что при чтении "лишние" два байта не инициализированы сознательно (а могут содержать что угодно — от просто мусора до служебной информации о кадре стека), а при записи — могут просто испортить какую-то другую переменную или ту же служебную информацию о кадре стека, что (теоретически) может привести, например, в возврату из функции в совсем другую точку кода, а не в точку вызова.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Никак не мог понять почему винда так просто даёт мне портить память. Только теперь понял, что переменная же в стеке, и с чего винда не должна давать мне менять память которая принадлежит моему процессу. С 200к вас, Harry

Comment: @Bloody.cpp *С 200к вас, Harry* — как говорили в моё время, "*не говори "гоп!", не переехав Чоп*" :) — есть такая пограничная станция... Мне еще 400 очков собрать надо :)

Comment: Странно, но у меня в авторе ответа пишет, что у вас 200k, при этом в профиле пишет 199.601 реп. Но ладно, я дождусь момента когда у вас будет 200k и поздравлю вас :) @Harry

Comment: @Bloody.cpp Округление, округление :)

Answer (score 2):

Формально - неопределённое поведение.

Реально - при чтении половина инта будет мусором. А при записи - порча некоторого куска памяти. Хотя если повезёт, то ненужного из-за выравнивания данных.

Comment: ... если архитектура позволяет размещать инты на адресах не кратных четырем.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, логичное замечание. Впрочем, более вероятно, что он случайно окажется кратен 4.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор ничего не выделит. Вы либо получите исключение, либо получите переменную с мусором если попытаетесь получить значение. Если попытаетесь записать туда что-то - возможно получите исключение. Нужно понимать, что в памяти ничего не подразделяется на цифры или не цифры, символы или не символы. Всё состоит из байтов, а они из битов. Потому ничего волшебного вы не получите

Comment: Поясните, почему в https://ideone.com/sPWJAS так и нет исключения, несмотря на большие буквы в вашем **ТОЧНО получите исключение**?

Comment: Ох нет, кажется я немножко лоханулся.. А нет :) После вывода в консоль мне сразу прилетает исключение "Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted". Запускаю в visual studio 2019 @Harry

Comment: Хотя, вполне возможно, что менеджер памяти не особо то и злиться, на то, что я беру эти 2 байта. Ведь они скорее всего не принадлежат никакому процессу. @Harry

Comment: *После вывода в консоль мне сразу прилетает исключение "Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted".* Разве что в отладочном режиме. Скомпилировал VC++ 2019, запустил — никаких исключений. Ну не оговорено нигде конкретно такое поведение — исключение, ни в каком стандарте. UB и не более того, что означает, что исключение *возможно*, но не гарантировано.

Comment: Ладно, ошибся. Исправил ответ. Но так всё равно делать не надо, всё же не просто так исключение наверное выдаётся. @Harry

Comment: То, о чем вы написали — не исключение (вы не перехватите его даже с включенным `/EHa`), а дополнительная проверка (т.н. "канарейка") в среде в отладочном режиме (ну или явно включаемая ключиком `/RTCs` *без включения оптимизации*, но еще раз — выполнение просто завершится без перехвата исключения в `catch`) (см. [описание](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-native-run-time-checks?view=vs-2022)). Все эти проверки выполняются за счет снижения производительности...